# How to get types of variables that are inside a class?

Tags: typescript

I want to get types of specific variable inside a class e.g:

```
class FakePerson {
    name: string = "";
    age: number = 0;
    ID?: number = undefined;
}
```

```
getVaribleType(FakePerson, "name") => string
getVaribleType(FakePerson, "age") => number
getVaribleType(FakePerson, "ID") => number | undefined
```

I had tried gaining it via using `Object.keys(new FakePerson())` and then `typeof (object  as any)[key]`.

Unfortunately this limit me in default variables of `new FakePerson()`, so I can't get true **ID** type (gain undefined, not number | undefined).

Comment: The type system only exists at compiletime, not at runtime. It's not possible to examine the compiletime types and print them at runtime as you are trying to do here. Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Do you **have** to do this, can your requirement be fulfilled via other means, e.g., by only using the types when the compiler is present?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a utility type for this using the [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility type that is built into TypeScript to first narrow an object type down to a single specified property, and then accessing that property using square bracket notation to get its type.

For example, see the `PropType` utility type here:

```js
class FakePerson {
    name: string = "";
    age: number = 0;
    ID?: number = undefined;
}

type PropType<T, P extends keyof T> = Pick<T, P>[P]

type NameType = PropType<FakePerson, "name">; // string
type AgeType = PropType<FakePerson, "age">; // age
type IdType = PropType<FakePerson, "ID">; // number | undefined
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiYGsCmAFJAnCB7AdtA3gLABQ0Z0OYAtkgFzQQAu6AljgObQC80ARLwG4S5aGHZ0KAVyoAjDN2gAGIaXIBJACIB+ejmlz0CyTgAmSAGZskJlQF8SJRgE8ADkmgp0WFwBVXSAB4fABoPaCQAD0YkUxhkJyxzaB8APgUUFmAEINCUFIBtFABdB2JnN2gAOWokPwqeT286wPhkNExcUN5KGl4UgWgAekGGZjZ2R39oAEFxZvSvX38A1tQMbBwusSQ+geHRcUmKtRN5hsXmlcQ1js2+TV2hkb1ZeQAfaGMzSxxrEiA)

Comment: It works, but I want to compare this value (e.g. number | undefined) to typeof of a "random" variable;